# Connect via public IP to a Dedicated Game Server in a VM in a NAS

Tags: networking

As the title suggests, however, my ISP provides a Private IP (10.x.x.x) with NAT between my internal network (192.168.x.x) and my public IP (180.x.x.x). And I do not have a static IP. I have a few scenarios and I can't say I'm very knowledgeable in networking so kindly bear with me.

That said, I have setup a Virtual Machine (CentOS 8) in my NAS and ran a dedicated server for a video game that uses UDP connection. I have tested connecting to it via local IP and it works. However, I could not connect to it via the Private IP, and especially not via the Public IP even though I have added port forwarding rules and even added a static route.

The second scenario is, I also ran the same dedicated server in my PC, and with this one I could connect via local IP and Private IP. But not through Public IP, which I guess is to be expected as I've read in my searches it's because of NAT.

My aim is to be able to connect directly (via Public IP) to the game's dedicated server running in my NAS via VM. Is there a way to do this? Might there be configurations in the VM, NAS and/or Router that I've missed? My router is a Huawei HG8145v5 which was provided by my ISP, and I can't even set it to Bridge mode.

Is there anything I can do on my end? Hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Your terminology is a little confusing. By _dedicated server_, do you mean a game’s server software? Please confirm that your ISP does carrier-grade NAT: Your router  does not have a public IP address on it’s WAN interface (as indicated by its web interface)?

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP is incompetent.  They shpuld not be using 10.x.x.x on customer grar - there us a different rangr for Carrier Grade NAT.

Your options are to get a non NAT WAN IP address or get a VPN which offers you a static IP address (Google VPN static IP - it is a different use case from the typical privacy use case, but the protocol is the same, and many companies provide it).

There are some alternatives like getting  your ISP to port forward the relevant ports - but they are unlikely to do this in a competent and sustained way.  Alternatively, if they provide IPv6 connectivity you may be able to use IPv6 instead - although that will depend on your game and other users also being on IPv6 - lots of systems still are not.